# My area calculator runs wrong and doesnt give me an error. Am a beginner so i have no clue what's going on

Tags: javascript

```js
alert("Welcome to the area calculator!");
prompt("Would you like to calculate the area of a 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional object? Type in either 2D or 3D") === objectDimension;
// User chooses dimension
if (objectDimension === "2d") {
  // user chooses shape
  prompt("What shape would you like to find the area of? You can choose from a rectangle, circle, or triangle.") === chosenShape;
} else if (objectDimension === "3d") {
  // user chooses 3D object
  prompt("What 3D object would you like to find the area of. You can choose anything as long as it's a cube.") === chosenShape;
}

function calculateAreaRectangle(Length, Width) {
  alert("The area of the rectangle is " + Length * Width + " units.");
}

function calculateAreaCube(Length, Width, Height) {
  alert("The area of the cube is " + Length * Width * Height + " units.");
}

function calculateAreaTriangle(Base, Height) {
  alert("The area of the triangle is " + Base * Height * .5 + " units.");
}

function calculateAreaCircle(Radius) {
  alert("The area of the circle is approximately " + 3.14 * Radius * Radius + "units, if 3.14 is used for pi.");
}

// 3D shape function calling
if (chosenshape === "cube") {
  calculateAreaCube(
    prompt("What is the length of this cube?"),
    prompt("What is the width of this cube?"),
    prompt("What is the height of this cube?")
  )
}
// 2D shape function calling
else if (chosenshape === "rectangle") {
  calculateAreaRectangle(
    prompt("What is the length of this rectangle?"),
    prompt("What is the width of this rectangle?")

  )
} else if (chosenshape === "circle") {
  calculateAreaCircle(
    prompt("What is the radius of this circle?")

  )
} else if (chosenshape === "triangle") {
  calculateAreaTriangle(
    prompt("What is the base of this triangle?"),
    prompt("What is the height of this triangle?")

  )
}
```

I don't understand why my area calculator won't work. When I use it goes straight to cube and doesn't give me an error. What am I doing wrong? I am a complete beginner to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The syntax `prompt(...) === variable` is incorrect. This simply returns a boolean value of whether the two are entirely equal, whereas I assume you want something more along the lines of `variable = prompt()`, which sets the variable to the resulting string from the prompt. Also, `===` is a case-sensitive evaluation. Seems strange to ask the user to enter `"2D"` or `"3D"` and then only move forward if they've entered `"2d"` or `"3d"`.

Comment: What's this supposed to do: `prompt("Would you like to calculate the area of a 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional object? Type in either 2D or 3D") === objectDimension;
`?

Comment: Run the code snippet in the OP. It gives you the error lol..

Comment: It would be best if you learned about [how to debug JavaScript in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging/2282/stepping-through-code#t=201707252003534771804), and perhaps found a tutorial on basics like assignment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be confused on how to assign values to variables. You have

```
prompt("Would you like to calculate the area of a 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional object? Type in either 2D or 3D") === objectDimension;
```

but this compares the result of `prompt(...)` to `objectDimension` which hasn't been defined which the console tells you. What you want to do is first declare your variable then assign it for example:

```
var objectDimension = prompt("Would you like to calculate the area of a 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional object? Type in either 2D or 3D");
```

A more complete example of assignment and comparison:

```js
var result;

result = prompt("Enter 1 or 2");

if(result === "1"){
    alert("You entered the number one!")
} else if(result == "2") {
    alert("You entered the number 2!")
} else {
    alert("Y u no listen")
}
```

The `==` and `===` are for comparison while `=` is for assignment. You may want to read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_variables.htm) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_ifelse.htm) for more help

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues.

1) assign the value of the prompt to a variable like this. 
  var value = prompt("caption");

2) variables are case sensitive.  you have chosenshape and chosenShape.  pick one and stick with it.

```
alert("Welcome to the area calculator!");

// set objectDimension to the value of the prompt call
var objectDimension = prompt("Would you like to calculate the area of a 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional object? Type in either 2D or 3D");

// User chooses dimension



// Recommended to use .trim() and .toLower() on the prompt value to remove     spaces and change it to 2d (incase the entered 2D)


if (objectDimension.trim().toLowerCase() === "2d") {
    // user chooses shape
    var chosenShape = prompt("What shape would you like to find the area of? You can choose from a rectangle, circle, or triangle.");
} else if (objectDimension.trim().toLowerCase() === "3d") {
    // user chooses 3D object
    var chosenShape = prompt("What 3D object would you like to find the area of. You can choose anything as long as it's a cube.");
}

function calculateAreaRectangle(Length, Width) {
    alert("The area of the rectangle is " + Length * Width + " units.");
}

function calculateAreaCube(Length, Width, Height) {
    alert("The area of the cube is " + Length * Width * Height + " units.");
}

function calculateAreaTriangle(Base, Height) {
    alert("The area of the triangle is " + Base * Height * .5 + " units.");
}

function calculateAreaCircle(Radius) {
    alert("The area of the circle is approximately " + 3.14 * Radius * Radius + "units, if 3.14 is used for pi.");
}

// 3D shape function calling
// variables are case sensitive.  changed to chosenShape from chosenshape
if (chosenShape === "cube") {
    calculateAreaCube(
        prompt("What is the length of this cube?"),
        prompt("What is the width of this cube?"),
        prompt("What is the height of this cube?")
    )
}
// 2D shape function calling
else if (chosenShape === "rectangle") {
    calculateAreaRectangle(
        prompt("What is the length of this rectangle?"),
        prompt("What is the width of this rectangle?")

    )
} else if (chosenShape === "circle") {
    calculateAreaCircle(
        prompt("What is the radius of this circle?")

    )
} else if (chosenShape === "triangle") {
    calculateAreaTriangle(
        prompt("What is the base of this triangle?"),
        prompt("What is the height of this triangle?")

    )
}
```